# Finding a value in one colunm that matches another column then putting that value in a third column (excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

All of the values are texts since the are usernames that are from two different systems.
so one column has:

Column A            Column B
smit19108            Fred99015
Fred99015            Smit1908

So the whole thing is a mess but basically I want to pull the ones that match and put them into a third column that will be just the ones that are in both.
I tried index, and match but I am not well versed in Excel so any help would be great.
Thanks in advance
Tim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find and keep matches from 2 columns in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/338613/find-and-keep-matches-from-2-columns-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need values found in both columns, you only need to search one column for each value found in the other column.  To do this, you could use the following formula in cell C1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1, A:A, 0)), "", B1)
```

Then copy-paste C1 down until the end of column B.  This would display the value of the cell in column B if the same value is found in column A.  It would display a blank value if not.

Then you could sort by column C to group all of the non-blank cells and blank cells together to have your list of values found in both columns.

To put your sorted values at the top of the list, you could use a value like `"ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"` for a non-match instead of `""` and then use conditional formatting to hide those cells.

The [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function looks for the value in `B1` in the range `A:A`.  The `0` specifies that it must be an exact match.  If no match is found, an error is returned, which is why we check for an error with the [`ISERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/iserror-function-6a5f3e99-40bc-43ce-a7c8-e79b7b6af5d5) function.  The [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb) function then returns an empty value as specified with `""` if the `MATCH` function returned an error, or it returns the value of `B1` if the result of the `MATCH` function did not return an error.

Comment: Perfect Thanks for the quick response, even though I have been slow on response.